# Vue and Firebase real time database get push ID values

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a simple game of Tic Tac Toe using Vue and Firebase.

I want to have open games shown to the end user, and games that are "full", having 2 players already will not be shown to the user.

The part of the Vue code I'm having trouble with is:

```js
firebase: {
  games: db.ref("games")
},
```

It returns the full games object shown in the image, which is great, but I want to filter it so that it only returns objects where "show" = "true".

Firebase does have a "equalTo" function, but I can't figure out how to get around the randomly generated push ID's.

Any help most appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```js
db.ref("games").orderByChild("show").equalTo("true")
```

here is the docs on [sorting & filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data)